# Intensity map using GWT

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, gwt-visualization

Google has a library for GWT gwt-visualization (can be obtained [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/Downloads?tm=2)). I tried to find an example on how to draw intensity heat ([IntensityMap](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/IntensityMap.html)) map but was not able to find anything.
What I'm trying to achieve is to create a city map and the intensity circles over the cities. Similar to [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#markersexample) image below.

[image: Intensity map]

So, my question is how do I make such a map using GWT using gwt-visualization library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot a `GeoChart` is used and not an `IntensitiyMap`.
So if you use the `IntensityMap` from gwt-visualization it will look like [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intensitymap) and not like the screenshot you posted. 
Unfortunately there is no ''GeoChart'' wrapper in the gwt-visualization (there is only one for the old [GeoMap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap)).

It is really easy to implement a wrapper for an existing google chart (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationNewWrapper) for more details). You can take an existing wrapper as an example and modify it.

I created a [wrapper](https://github.com/timeu/maven-repos/tree/master/releases/at/gmi/nordborglab/widgets/geochart/0.1.2) for the ''GeoChart'' because I needed one for one of  my projects. You can use it and also modify it as you like.